# Show that $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(W_t^2-t)_{t \geq 0}$ are not uniformly integrable

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales, uniform-integrability

I'm considering the following martingale $M_t:=W_t^2-t,\ t\geq 1$, where the $W_t$ is a Brownian motion. I want to prove that this martingale and the Brownian motion are not uniformly integrable. I don't see how I should proceed in other to check that the following term goes not to $0$.

$\lim_{K\rightarrow \infty}\sup_{t\geq0}\mathbb{E}[\mid X_t\mid I_{\mid X\mid>K}]$ for $X=M$ and $X=W$

Comment: For $X=W$ we know that $X_t \sim N(0,t)$ and this means that $\mathbb{E}(|X_t| 1_{\{|X_t|>K\}})$ can be calculated explicitly.

Comment: sure you are right. So that means that $\lim_{K\rightarrow \infty}\sup_{t\geq 0}\mathbb{E}[\mid W_t\mid I_{\mid W\mid>K}]=\lim_{K\rightarrow \infty}\sup_{t\geq 0}2e^{\frac{-k^2}{2t}}=\lim_{K\rightarrow \infty}2=2$. Am I right? And for $X=M$?

Comment: No, you didn't calculate the integral correctly.

Comment: oh yes!! I see. I forgot the factor $\sqrt{2\pi t}$. Thank you so much.

Comment: Every uniformly integrable family is bounded in $L^1$. To answer your question, note simply that, by scaling, $$E(|W_t|)=\sqrt{t}\,E(|W_1|)\qquad E(|M_t|)=t\,E(|M_1|)$$ hence the processes $(W_t)$ and $(M_t)$ are both unbounded in $L^1$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Brownian motion, Solution I**

Since $W_t \sim N(0,t)$, we have

$$\mathbb{E}(|W_t| 1_{\{|W_t|>K\}}) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \int_K^{\infty} x \exp \left( -\frac{x^2}{2t} \right) \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sqrt{t} \exp \left(-\frac{K^2}{2t} \right)$$

and therefore

$$\sup_{t \geq 0} \mathbb{E}(|W_t| 1_{\{|W_t|>K\}})=\infty.$$

**Brownian motion, Solution II**

Fix $K \geq 1$. Then, using that $W_t \stackrel{d}{=} \sqrt{t} W_1$,

$$\mathbb{E}(|W_t| 1_{\{|W_t|>K\}}) \geq \mathbb{P}(|W_t|>K) = \mathbb{P}\left(|W_1| > \frac{K}{\sqrt{t}} \right) \stackrel{t \to \infty}{\to} 1.$$

Consequently,

$$\lim_{K \to \infty} \sup_{t \geq 0} \mathbb{E}(|W_t| 1_{\{|W_t|>K\}})\geq 1.$$

**(Non)Uniform integrability of $M_t := W_t^2-t$**

For $K \geq 1$, we have by the triangle inequality

$$\mathbb{E}(|M_t| 1_{\{|M_t|>K\}}) \geq \mathbb{P}(|M_t|>K) \geq \mathbb{P}(|W_t|^2 > K-t).$$

Using again the scaling property, we find

$$\mathbb{E}(|M_t| 1_{\{|W_t|>K\}}) \geq \mathbb{P} \left( |W_1|^2 > \frac{K-t}{t} \right). \tag{1}$$

Choosing $t = K/2$, we get

$$\begin{align*}\lim_{K \to \infty} \sup_{t \geq 0} \mathbb{E}(|M_t| 1_{\{|M_t|>K\}}) &\geq \liminf_{K \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|M_{K/2}| 1_{\{|M_{K/2}|>K\}}) \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{\geq} \mathbb{P}(|W_1|^2 > 1) >0. \end{align*}$$

This shows that $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is not uniformly integrable.

Comment: For a somewhat simpler approach, see my comment to the question.

Comment: @Did I agree that your solution is much more clever; however, I think that it is also nice to have a "direct" proof (which shows how to deal with the expression in the definition of uniform integrability).

Comment: Please do not argue about the merits of your answer, it is allright.

Comment: @Did Don't worry; I know that it is alright :)

Comment: @saz I was going to open a new thread but I found your useful answer. Just a question: when you write 
$$\mathbb{E}(|M_t| 1_{\{|W_t|>K\}}) \geq \mathbb{P} \left( |W_1|^2 > \frac{K-t}{t} \right). \tag{1}$$ , could I just note that 

the last term is $\int_{\sqrt{\frac{K - t}{t}}}^{\infty} 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$ and the supremum over $t$ is taken with $t=K$ and hence the value of the integral is exaclty $\frac{1}{2}$ and hence uniform integrability does not hold?

Comment: @Vefhug Yeah, that's fine.