# A martingale $(X_t)_{t\geqslant 0}$ which is bounded in $L^{1}$ but not uniformly integrable.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Is there any examples of the martingale $X(t)$ which is bounded in $L^{1}$ but not uniformly integrable?

I've just known that $$M_t=\mathrm{e}^{aW_t-a^2t/2}$$ with $a$ not $0$ and $W$ a Brownian Motion is a martingale but not uniformly integrable.

Is there any other examples which are more concrete and more constructive?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean concrete and more constructive? Exponential martingales like the one you have arise quite naturally.

Comment: I mean examples which could be directly found not uniformly integrable. Not via contradiction as the one I have arised.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples

1. [Show that $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(W_t^2-t)_{t \geq 0}$ are not uniformly integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332652/show-that-w-t-t-geq-0-and-w-t2-t-t-geq-0-are-not-uniformly-integr?rq=1)
2. from [Martingale not uniformly integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352570/martingale-not-uniformly-integrable)

> Let $\xi_j$ be i.i.d. with $(\forall j \in \mathbb{N}) \mbox{} \mathbb{P}(\xi_j=0)=\mathbb{P}(\xi_j=2)=1/2$, and define $M_n=\prod_{j=1}^n \xi_j$ for $n\geq 0$. Then $(M_n)$ is a non-negative martingale with $\mathbb{E}(M_n)=1$ for all $n$. But $M_n\to 0$ almost surely, so $(M_n)$ cannot be uniformly integrable.

3. [Proof of a martingale not being uniformly integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4462663/proof-of-a-martingale-not-being-uniformly-integrable)

4.From [Uniformly Integrable Martingale](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/615968/uniformly-integrable-martingale)
The $(Y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a seq. of positive, independent r.v.'s whose expectation is 1 $\forall n$ satisfying
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{Y_{k}})=0$$.
Then $\xi_{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}$ is a $\mathcal{F_{n}}$-martingale that is not uniformly-integrable.